# Как генерировать случайные айдишники?

Tags: индексы

Хочу защититься от перебора, но не могу найти правил хорошего тона как это сделать, кроме rand ничего путного в голову не приходит.

```
"user_id_" . rand()
```

Но как то слишком очевидно что ли.

Comment: uuid, например

Comment: @dimka3210, случайная величина нормально защитит от перебора, если сделать ее достаточно длинной. Можно делать хэш от кучи параметров, включая рандом, айпишник, серверное время, браузер пользователя - без явного знания алгоритма его будет сложно подобрать, плюс сам рандом внесет защиту от воссоздания хэша по известным параметрам.

Comment: @Etki, пользователей отпугивают нечитаемые строки. Хеш - слишком много байт для id. Если только не брать кусочек хеша. Например 6-8 символов. Но хотелось бы как нибудь интами (int) рулить. Да и как это лучше делать то? Две колонки в базе или одна но строкой и на неё индекс уникальности вешать?

    | 123 | 567 | против | '123_567' |

Comment: up up up up

Comment: А что за перебор? Ну переберет злоумышленник и найдет живой `id`, а дальше то что? Как то торможу. Приведите конкретный кейс атаки.

Comment: @Barmaley это для случаев, когда этот id показывается пользователю за каким-то фигом, вот в домино пицце была уязвимость - берешь заказ ближайщий к своему собственному и можно узнать адреса и имена людей которые заказывали пиццу кроме тебя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Математика вам в помощь. Пример для PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT ((((nextval('t1_id_seq'::regclass))::numeric * 
                (678223072849::bigint)::numeric) 
                % ((1000000000)::bigint)::numeric) 
                + (<SOME_OFFSET_VALUE>::bigint)::numeric)
);
```

Это биективное отображение N -> N для всех N от 0 до 999999999. На вид выглядит как выбор случайных чисел.

Comment: Откуда взялось 678223072849?

Answer (score 3):

А можно просто подобрать функцию, которая однозначно будет преобразовывать id. Наружу выдавать преобразованный. Самая простая функция - переставлять биты местами. Но можно пойти дальше. Навряд ли будет 4млд пользователей, поэтому два бита отводим для контрольной суммы (они могут быть и в по середине). Специальный код следит за тем, что бы контрольная сумма совпадала. Если нет - ставит аккуратно бан.

Answer (score 2):

можно сгенерить таблицу с последовательными id, перемешать ее, перенумеровать, потом брать их оттуда

```
real_id | random_id
1       | 1234432
2       | 5645234
```